# Use sed or grep in bash script to check if file ends with specific string

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file called output.txt on my ubuntu server, how do I use sed or grep to check if the last two characters in the file are "nt" The text in the file is below, I expect my if statement to return true in this case.

> The Senate passed a six-bill package to fund parts of the federal
> government through September, narrowly avoiding a partial shutdown
>
> The upper chamber voted 75 to 22, sending the bill to President
> Biden's desk before a midnight deadline
>
> Mr. Biden was expected to sign the bill Saturday
>
> Republicans' demands for amendment votes on immigration-related and
> other measures slowed its passage and threatened to push the final
> vote to Saturday, after funding lapsed
>
> "We have good news for the country," Senate Majority Leader Chuck
> Schumer, a New York Democrat, said ahead of vote
>
> "We will keep important programs funded for moms and kids, for
> veterans, for the environment, for housing and so much more. Because
> both sides cooperated today, we've taken a major step towards our goal
> of fully funding the government

Comment: Use `sed -n '$p'` to output the last line, then grep for `nt$`.

Comment: @choroba please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Do you REALLY mean `the last two characters in the file are "nt"` or do you actually mean `the last two characters in the file **before the terminating newline** are "nt"`? If you mean the former then what you have is not a valid text file per POSIX since all text files are required to end with a newline and so YMMV trying to use any text-processing tool to read it. If you mean the latter then please make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't really use `sed` or `grep` here. You can, but in my opinion, `tail` is simpler. Use `tail` to get the last three bytes—we need three to account for the trailing `\n` character—of the file (note that this won't work if instead of `nt` you are looking for a more complicated Unicode string where characters can be more than one byte each), and then check if that matches `nt`:

```sh
if [ "$(tail -c3 file)" = "nt" ]; then 
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

You could do this with GNU `grep`, for instance by treating the entire file (assuming it doesn't contain NUL characters) as a single "line" and checking the last characters:

```sh
if grep -qPz 'nt\n$' file; then
 echo yes
else
 echo no
fi
```

Or, with `sed`, something like this (or @steeldriver's better and simpler [GNU-specific approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771943/22222)) :

```sh
if [ "$(sed -n '${/nt$/p;}' file | wc -c)" -gt 0 ]; then 
  echo yes; 
else 
  echo no
fi
```

Or even `perl`:

```sh
if perl -ne '$l=$_; }{ exit($l=~/nt$/ ? 0 : 1)' file; then 
 echo yes
else
 echo no
fi
```

Comment: Or `perl -ne 'exit !/nt$/ if eof'`, but seeking to end-3 for seekable files would make it more efficient.

Comment: Beware that in bash (contrary to zsh) `[ "$(tail -c3 file)" = "nt" ]` would also return yes for a file ending in `$'\0nt'` (not followed by a newline).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but in this case, I would consider that a feature not a bug since what the OP really cares about is whether the file "ends" with `nt` to the human eye, I doubt they care about the trailing `\n`. A bigger issue, IMO, is that bash will return false for `[ "$(tail -c3 file)" = "nt" ]` for a file ending in `nt\r\n` while the spirit of this question suggests it should return true.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu has GNU sed, whose **q**uit command has an extension to return a status code, so you can address the last line and exit with status 0 if it ends in `nt` or non-zero otherwise, ex.

```
 if sed -n '${/nt$/q0;q1}' output.txt; then ...
```

You may want to set the non-zero status to something greater than 4 to distinguish it from sed's other possible [exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Exit-status).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. Raku has Boolean `True` and `False` (enum) values. Coercion via either the  `Bool` routine or the equivalent `so` (*"is it so?"*) routine produces the desired `True`/`False` output.

---

**Ignoring trailing-whitespace:**

*Using a filehandle (i.e. `$fh.eof`):*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open;  \
            .match(/ nt \h* $/).Bool.say if $fh.eof for $fh.lines;'  file
```

*Using `lines.tail`:*

```perl
~$ raku -e '.match(/ nt \h* $/).Bool.say for lines.tail;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'lines.tail.match(/ nt  \h* $/).Bool.put;'  file
```

*Even simpler `lines.tail`:*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'm/ nt \h* $/.so.put for lines.tail;'  file
```

---

**Removing or otherwise handling trailing-whitespace:**

The answers in the top section do a good job returning `True` if the last line ends with `nt`, and `False` otherwise. But the answers in the top section will return `False` if the file merely contains one-or-more trailing newlines. To give a more accurate Boolean answer, trailing whitespace can be dealt with as per below:

*Remove (single) terminal newline and any resultant trailing-whitespace:*

```perl
~$ raku -e '.match(/ nt $/).Bool.say for lines.tail(2).chomp.trim-trailing;'  file
```

*Remove all trailing blank lines (via `slurp`):*

```perl
~$ raku -e '.match(/ nt $/).Bool.say for slurp.trim-trailing;'  file
```

*Skip over trailing blank lines (via `lines` and `chars`):*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $fh = $*ARGFILES.IO.open;  \
             my $a = $_ if .chars for $fh.lines();  \
             $a.match(/ nt $/).Bool.say;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my $a = $_ if .chars for lines(); put $a ~~ m/ nt $/.so;'  file
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Bool
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

Here's an very simple example on how to achieve it using both grep and sed:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

result=$(grep -o 'nt$' 'Output.txt' | sed '$!d')
if [ "$result" = 'nt' ]; then
   echo 'Matched !'
else
   echo 'Not found !'
fi
```

**Explain:**

- -o Prints only the matched part.
- $ Matches at every ending of line
- '$!d' Deletes all lines except the last one.

Comment: This will report “Matched !” if ***any*** line ends with “`nt`”, not just the last one.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I have updated the example, now it's will parse the last returned value.

Comment: That tests that a line ending with `nt` is present somewhere in the file and, redundantly, that the last line that ends with `nt` does indeed end with `nt`, not that the last line of the input ends with `nt`. Try `printf 'rant\nfoo\n' > Output.txt; grep -o 'nt$' 'Output.txt' | sed '$!d'` and you'll see it outputs `nt` despite the file not ending with `nt`.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, the code I wrote does not works as expected !